# Will I have learned the prerequisites for self learning stochastic calculus and monte carlo method?

Tags: soft-question, stochastic-calculus, advice, monte-carlo

I'm an undergraduate econ major, and my main focus is in actuarial sciences, which as you may or may not know it's pretty mathematical. Some of the topics I will have to learn at some point on my own is stochastic calculus, stochastic differential equations, and the monte carlo method. So in my own experience I have taken probability theory, a full calculus sequence (all of Thomas' Calculus book), and linear algebra. With these classes alone will that be enough to learn the previously listed topics? If not, what else should I learn?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to add the topics names in the title to get a wider response.

Comment: @Learner I thought about it but I didn't want to make too long of a title. Perhaps I will add one of them in there.

Comment: Learn $\ {\bf{\tt C++}}\ $ and practice yourself some little problems at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You could go on to learn

- Real Analysis
- Measure Theory
- Functional Analysis

Plus any advanced courses on Probability theory, stochastic processes or statistics would not harm.

Comment: I'd like to learn more about the topics you posted but I can't for a long time because I need to focus on financial mathematics, and attaining credentials and certifications. Do you think that given my current experience I'd be successful in learning those topics I listed? Or am I missing prerequisites?

Comment: @Kyle it would be very useful to understand measure theory and functional analysis before studying stochastic PDEs

Comment: @oldrinb Isn't measure theory more important because measure theory is needed at the very start of probability theory?