# Stochastic Calculus Self-Study Background required

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, finance

I am a CS graduate with working knowledge of calculus, probability and stats. I passed my CFA 2. I currently work 9-5 at a bulge bracket bank.

I plan to attend a good MFE program in the fall of next year. As part of my pre-MFE prep, I am devoting my evenings to study the math pre-requisites with gusto.

Currently, I am doing the following:

- Solved and worked through Differential and integral calculus by N.Piskunov
- Completed chapters 1-3 & reading further, elements of real analysis, Bartle
- Reading and solving Elements of Integration and Lebesgue measure

Given that, I have time only until May '17, it would be extremely helpful, if someone could recommend just the precise set of topics to study from the below areas

- Real Analysis
- Measure theory essentials
- measure-theoretic probability & renewals, queues and martingales
- ODEs and PDEs essentials

before my classes start. While I am not a math major, the goal is at the end of the course, I want to be really good at my stuff.

I am enjoying the real analysis proofs and I think that's a good rigorous start.

Thanks,
Quasar.

Comment: What happens May '17 - Sep '17?

Comment: I will have started my course hopefully by June '17. :)

Comment: any particular reason the course begins in June? Most courses begin in September right?

Comment: You are right. They all begin in Sep. I am also applying to just one at Singapore, which begins in June. :)

Comment: you started already?

Comment: Quasar, how are you? Haha

Comment: I am doing fine. How are things at your end? Great to hear after long.

Comment: @BCLC Hope you are well. I would like to connect to you offline. I enrolled for and undergraduate mathematics course, currently in the first year

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will I have learned the prerequisites for self learning stochastic calculus and monte carlo method?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360362/will-i-have-learned-the-prerequisites-for-self-learning-stochastic-calculus-and)

Comment: @user95921, imho the answer below includes all topics on the critical path. The books I used were (i) Stephen Abbott's UA, (ii) selected topics from Capinski - measure/expectation, (iii) convergence theorems - Grimmett & Stirzaker and (iv) A first course in stochastic calculus written by quant & trader, L.P. Arguin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Advanced Probability Theory (Probability with Martingales by David Williams of course!)

- Measure Spaces
- Events
- Random Variables
- Independence
- Integration
- Expectation
- WLLN, SLLN, CLT
- Conditional Expectation
- Martingales
- Convergence of Random Variables
- Uniform Integrability
- Characteristic Functions

### Basic Real Analysis (Lay Analysis with an Introduction to Proof or Ross Elementary Analysis*)

- Real Numbers (inf, sup, Heine-Borel, Bolzano-Weierstrass)
- Functions, Limits, Continuity
- Definitions, Existence, Properties of Integrals
- Sequences of Real Numbers
- Sequences of Functions

### Advanced Real Analysis (Royden Fitzpatrick - Real Analysis)

- Lebesgue Measure
- Lebesgue Measurable Functions
- Lebesgue Integral

### ODE and PDE

These were barely touched in my stochastic calculus classes. I think the only thing relevant here is solving second order linear ODEs.

I guess there are/can be links between DE and stochastic calculus/analysis as you go deeper into certain areas, but I don't think these are required for basics of stochastic calculus/analysis.

### Measure Theory

My advanced probability and stochastic calculus classes needed only real analysis classes as prerequisites. It seems the basics of measure theory are already covered in Lebesgue Measure and Lebesgue Measurable Functions in Real Analysis and Measure Spaces, Events, Random Variables and Integration in Advanced Probability.

### Basic Probability Theory

Don't forget Basic Probability Theory. Be sure to understand basic set theory, independence of events, independence of random variables, moment generating functions, conditional probability and conditional expectation on events before going into independence of sigma-algebras, characteristic functions and conditional expectation on random variables or sigma-algebras.

---

*Trench Real Analysis was kinda hard for me to digest. idk. We used trench and lay in undergrad. I used Ross and Lay last year

Comment: The connection between multidimensional SDE and PDE involving the Laplacian is quite significant but otherwise it's not a big deal.

Comment: @Ian Feynman-Kac?

Comment: Feynman-Kac is one of those connections, yes.

Comment: @Ian what are some of the others please?

Comment: There are some connections where the probability side involves stopping times which arise through boundary conditions on the PDE side. For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946397/probability-that-a-brownian-motion-with-drift-hits-1-before-hitting-1-before-t/1959667#1959667

Comment: @Ian oh thanks. That looks more significant than FK because it involves series solutions

Comment: Nah, that's just me explicitly solving the PDE. The connection is still just "the solution to this probability problem is the solution to this PDE with these auxiliary conditions." And the PDE itself is the same as Feynman-Kac.

Comment: @Ian reread question and answer + your comments. The solution to the PDE gives the required probability right? If so it seems to suggest that probability theorists would be interested in solving PDEs for other/future probability problems? My context: In stochastic calculus class we used probability to solve a PDE. What you've shown me is that we've used PDE to compute a probability. So PDEs seem pretty significant to probability. Am I mistaking something here?